# Taking ideal sheaf which is not locally generated by sections, where does it fail to construct a closed subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be a sheaf of ideals on the scheme $X$ which is not necessarily locally generated by sections.

Following the construction of a closed subscheme where we set $Z = \text{supp}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I})$ and $\mathcal{O}_Z = i^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I})$ where $i: Z \rightarrow X$ denotes the inclusion, where does this construction fail to produce a closed subscheme of $X$ in general?

The subset $Z$ should be closed as the support of a sheaf of rings (or as a quotient of a sheaf which is locally generated by sections: $\mathcal{O}_X$). Further, using the definition of $\mathcal{O}_Z$, one should be able to prove that $i_*\mathcal{O}_Z \simeq \mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}$ from which we can deduce that the morphism of sheaves $i^\#:\mathcal{O}_X \to i_*\mathcal{O}_Z$ is surjective.

I'm pretty sure that I miss either a very subtile point or an even more obvious one. If you could help me out, I would appreciate that a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $R,\mathfrak m$ be a discrete valuation ring and $X=\operatorname {Spec}(R)=\{m,\eta\}$ be the associated affine scheme with generic point $\eta$ and closed point $m$.
Consider now  the (not quasi-coherent) ideal sheaf $\mathcal I\subset \mathcal O_X$ defined by $\mathcal I(X)=0$ and $\mathcal I(\{\eta\})=K$.
Its zero abelian group of global sections certainly doesn't generate the fibre $\mathcal I_\eta=K$.
The support of $\mathcal I$ is $\{\eta\}$, which is  not closed,  and $\mathcal I$ does not define a closed subscheme of $X$.

Comment: Dear @Georges Elencwajg. Thank you for your answer! I've seen this counter example in here before. But it does not tell me where my _plan_ above will fail. Your example shows me that $\mathcal{I}$ with non-closed support could not lead to a closed subscheme. Where does the absence of this property (which is implied by being locally generated by sections) really destroy the _plan_?

Comment: Now I wonder if my construction $(\text{supp}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}), i^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}))$ fails to be a scheme if $\mathcal{I}$ is not locally generated by sections...

Comment: Am I right if I say that your example does indeed fit very well since in that case my construction provides $\text{supp}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}) = \{m\}$ and that surely is no scheme.

Comment: Yes, $(m,( \mathcal O/ \mathcal I)_m)$ is not a scheme..

Comment: Then, again, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome, dear windsheaf.